# Create-based turtlebot simulation problem

Tags: ros, gazebo, irobot-create, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch turtlebot simulation with base = create the robot starts to constantly moving.

I changed file turtlebot_empty_world.launch in package turtlebot_gazebo:

```
<arg name="base"      value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BASE create)"/> <!-- create, roomba -->
<arg name="battery"   value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BATTERY /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0)"/>  <!-- /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 --> 
<arg name="stacks"    value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_STACKS circles)"/>  <!-- circles, hexagons --> 
<arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR kinect)"/>  <!-- kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->
```

I launch turtlebot now by command

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

It starts without errors, but, it doesn't stop slowly moving around by himself!

When the base was kobuki - the turtlebot stayed still.

I also tried to spawn pure irobot create in gazebo, it has the same problem, but I managed to solve it by adding gazebo plugin "differential drive". However, adding this plugin to turtlebot create base urdf file didn't help.

I'm really stuck with this issue, could you please at least point me to the digging direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146131/create-based-turtlebot-simulation-problem/) by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2014-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on 2014-04-22**:
@Ken_in_JAPAN thanks for your answer! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found this in ROS tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it

> Caution: Gazebo plugins for Create and Roomba bases don't work perfectly on Hydro, so expect strange behaviors when using them.

So the behaviour is undefined.

---

Originally posted by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) with karma: 220 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0